# Using thread.join() in Flask HTTP Route

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm writing a server for sending rendered images to clients (browsers) using **Flask**. Since an image maybe not ready (is still rendering), I wrote the following code to wait for a rendering thread until it finishes.

```
@app_autoView.route("/autoviewimgs/<origin>/<identifier>")
def autoviewimgs(origin, identifier):
    if identifier in renderThreads:
        renderThreads[identifier].join()
    return flask.send_from_directory(f'./latentspace/autoview/{origin}', identifier + '.png')
```

However, it seems the entire server start to wait for a single thread, and all other HTTP requests are blocked...

I don't know if python-threading is suitable for Flask or alternative ways of doing this...

I have tried Celery as suggested by @ParthS007, but the server was still blocked, as shown in the following code:

```
@app_autoView.route("/autoviewimgs/<origin>/<identifier>")
def autoviewimgs(origin, identifier):
    if identifier in renderThreads:
        if not renderThreads[identifier].ready():
            casename = renderThreads[identifier].get()
    return flask.send_from_directory(f'./latentspace/autoview/{origin}', identifier + '.png')
```

Comment: Don't use threads in web application. When run in the development server they will block, in a production setup they might get kicked by the WSGI server at any time.

Comment: Thanks so much. Are there any alternative ways to do something like `threading` in Flask?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, you're trying to receive one request from the user and then have the app use threading. For this, use something like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) where you can give tasks to worker threads.

Read more about design in [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/design/#thread-locals)